# Amaranth + Yogurt advisable in ayurveda?

Tags: nutrition, diet

According to ayurveda, is it a right combination to have amaranth and yogurt together? Also with maybe some fruit thrown in?

EDIT: i.e. does the combination have any negative/harmful effect on the body?
For reference here are a couple of links [link1](https://www.banyanbotanicals.com/info/ayurvedic-living/living-ayurveda/diet/ayurvedic-food-combining/) [link2](https://www.mindbodygreen.com/0-3615/10-Common-Food-Combinations-That-Wreak-Havoc-on-Your-Health.html) that mentions such combinations.

Excerpts:

"Food combining theory recommends to avoid mixing carbohydrates with acids. Adding dairy to this already difficult combo turns it into a recipe for digestive problems and after-meal fatigue"

Above statement is just an example (not really saying that it implies for my question). Want to know if amaranth and yogurt combination falls in any such harmful category?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). It is difficult to say if something is a "right combination" and the question is too broad. If you would like to ask about a certain health effect of the combination and narrow your question down, you can always [edit] it. If you throw in some research of your own, even better. For more information on cite policies, please take our [tour] and visit the [help]. Thanks!

Comment: ronilk:  A better question might be to ask if food combining theory is valid in general. I didn't upvote this question, but I might upvote the better question.  You can [edit] this question, and turn it into that question, if you like.

Comment: @tealhill i feel that might deviate from what i want to ask. I am no expert but from what i have read, i think food combining mostly is considered in ayurveda. So I will change the question to make it very specific. Thanks.